# Reset timer outside of loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, time

I've set up a timer for a function I am timing, but want it to reset after a condition is met

```
timestart = Time.now

Individual.all.each do |f|

    endtime = Time.now
    timer = (endtime - timestart)

    puts timer #places the time it takes for each loop

    if checktime  == 1 then
        ###Apply new {timestart = Time.now} HERE?###
    end

end
```

So in the above example, I want my timer to reset after 1min

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do after each 1 minute?

Comment: reset the timestart when 1min is reached, thus resetting the timer

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can use `yield` to clean up your main method

```
@timestart = Time.now

def one_min_check 
  start_time = Time.now
  yield
  end_time = Time.now
  puts "Something took #{end_time - start_time} to run"
  if end_time - @timestart >= 60.0
    @timestart = end_time 
    puts "Took 1 minute or longer. Reset 1 min at #{@timestart}"
  end
end


Individual.all.each do |f|
   one_min_check do 
     #do stuff with f
   end
end
```

But if why not just user benchmark?

```
require 'benchmark'

Individual.all.each do |f|
  puts Benchmark.measure do 
    #do stuff with f
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question as is in an easy Rails-like way to reset after a minute could be:

```
timestart = Time.now

Individual.all.each do |f|

    endtime = Time.now
    timer = (endtime - timestart)

    puts timer #places the time it takes for each loop

    if timestart < 1.minute.ago
        timestart = Time.now
    end

end
```

But, it's possible we could be more helpful if we understood why you want to benchmark the loop this way. Why do want to reset the timer every minute?

Also you have this comment: `places the time it takes for each loop`. That's not exactly true in your code here, since you aren't resetting timestart on every loop. Let's say the loop takes 1 second. The first iteration `timer` will be "1 second". The second time `timer` will be "2 seconds" even though the loop iteration took just a second.

But you might have your reasons :)

Comment: Thanks; I will try that out.  I'm fetching data from an API that has a limit of 600 requests/ 5 min, so I'm looking to add a timer and then a pause every 5 min; the timer is to calculate how long it needed to pause for before it can continue.  If there is a better way to do this I would love to know!

Comment: @JimBob I hope you are doing this in a background worker right?

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate it.

```
quantity = Individual.all.count
time = Benchmark.measure { Post.all }

time_per_each = time / quantity.to_f
```

The answer you get is in milisseconds, just convert.

Hope it help yout.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself :)

just placed the

```
timestart = Time.now
```

in the loop between the condition.  Had to change the code slightly to keep time, but the timer resets at that point for the next loop :->

Pretty easy really

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of what you are trying to do is correct :

```
timestart = Time.now

Individual.all.each do |f|

  puts Time.now-timestart #places the time it takes for each loop

  if Time.now-timestart < 60 # or some other condition of your choice
    timestart = Time.now
  end

end
```

should nicely do the job...

But indeed, it won't reset `timestart` on every loop